# Execute NSFetchRequest on application startup

Tags: objective-c, core-data

In another question ( [Accessing an NSApplications delegate in another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114011/accessing-an-nsapplications-delegate-in-another-class/) ) I asked about calling the Application's delegate because I needed it's managedObjectContext for a fetch request. However, when I try to let all values be displayed in an NSTableView on application startup, I'm running into problems. DataController, my NSTableViewDataSource, calls it's init-method before my application delegate calls it's applicationWillFinishStartup or any other method to initialize the managedObjectContext. What am I doing wrong? How else can I fill an NSTableView with already existing objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should access `managedObjectContext` only via its getter, even from `DataController`, as in `[appDelegate managedObjectContext]` or `appDelegate.managedObjectContext`.

Your `managedObjectContext` method should automatically set up the managed object context; you shouldn't write an explicit moc setup  routines in your `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, etc. And the standard core-data template is written that way.

Now, for this to work, the app delegate needs to be properly set up from the point of view of `DataController`. However, `init` is called before all the `IBOutlet` is set up, so that's the wrong place to perform setup operations of objects inside the nib. Instead, use `awakeFromNib` to do these things. `awakeFromNib` is sent to every object after the `IBOutlet` etc. are all set up.

That said, writing your own `DataController` is a total waste of time. Just instantiate the standard `NSArrayController` in the nib file, and use it in the Core Data mode via binding.  There's absolutely no need for you to write the fetch request by yourself. Study Apple's own CoreData sample codes and then google "Binding CoreData Tutorial" for many tutorials available on-line.

Comment: I've uploaded my project to dropbox as a zip file. I hope it helps: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22139493/Shop%20Helper.zip You might want to create some entries in the db before executing this since I removed some lines which added a new entry each time the application launches

Comment: OK, I'll rewrite my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. However, my application is designed to be the first step into core data instead of really having any particular use. Anyways, thank you for the hint